Sync package version between dependencies and build-system.requires
I have the following use case, which is quite common in deep learning workflows:

setup.py to build PyTorch C++/CUDA extensions [1, 2]:

from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension, CppExtension

setup(
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension(...),
        CppExtension(...),
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    }
)


pyproject.toml to build these extensions:

[project]
name = "mylibrary"
dependencies = [
    "torch",  # torch in dependencies
    "torchmetrics",
    "torchvision",
    ...
]
requires-python = ">=3.8"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "torch"]  # torch in build-system-requires
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

The issue is when doing pip install with isolation, two separate versions of torch might be used for building the extension and as a dependency for the package, which can lead to runtime errors.
Is there a way to tell setuptools that the two torch versions should be identical? Thanks!
P. S. I think using --no-build-isolation is one option, but that opens another can of worms for me. So I'd like to avoid this approach if possible.
